# How to pass array from js to controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js

I have an array in my javascript file `app/assets/javascript/pages/books_page.js` :

```
var booksPage = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    authors: []
  }
  ...
```

How can I pass that to my controller as a param. The path of my controller is `app/controllers/books_controller.rb` ?

I think I might need an ajax request and tried the following but it is not working:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/books_controller",
        data: { list_authors: this.get('authors') },
      });
```

Specifically, I am not sure what the url needs to be. Your help here will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone (and jQuery) should do all the heavy lifting for you. Set the [`urlRoot`](https://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) in the model:

```
var booksPage = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/books',
  ...
});
```

and then call [`save`](https://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) on the instance to send the data to the server:

```
// Get or create `books` as a `booksPage` instance as usual...
// Then make some changes to `books` using `books.set(...)`...
books.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
type: 'POST', 
url: `/books/${this.id}`, // or '/books/' + this.id,
data: {
  _method: 'put'
}
```

This will route you to the `BooksController#update`. You also need to merge the `_method` entry into your data object.

"NOTE: Because submitting forms with HTTP methods other than GET and POST isn't widely supported across browsers, all other HTTP methods are actually sent over POST with the intended method indicated in the _method parameter. Rails automatically detects and compensates for this." - [Working with JavaScript in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fb60def5a4d9eef95571b730701c55426846e0ea/guides/source/working_with_javascript_in_rails.md)

Comment: Why not just go with `type: 'put'`?

Comment: @muistooshort [2.4 How do forms with PATCH, PUT, or DELETE methods work?](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark) It's an old work around baked pretty deep into Rails to handle lack of browser support.

Comment: @muistooshort It is referenced as far back as at least [10 years ago](https://github.com/rails/rails/blame/e56b3e4c0b60b2b86f5ca9c5e5a0b22fa34d37ab/railties/guides/source/rails_on_rack.textile) in the Rails doumentation!

Comment: But you're not using a `<form>`.

Comment: @muistooshort shhh, don't let Rails know! "When parsing POSTed data, Rails will take into account the special _method parameter". The `_method` is used in POST requests, not only form submission. Take, for instance, a `remote: true` form sending back an AJAX request.

Comment: @muistooshort I do not know the full history or functionality.  I've traced it as far back as [Rack::MethodOverride](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/MethodOverride) at least [11 years ago](https://github.com/rack/rack/blame/5b60d28e922a662c9c5f30caed38e1a7d285e455/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're trying to get at here or what any of this has to do with avoiding basic HTTP and jQuery features.

Comment: @muistooshort Oh, I included it in my answer for the correctness of using `PUT` to update the Book instead of `POST`.   It is just a quirk of Rails and I thought you were interested in how/why Rails uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify`, and parse it from Controller `JSON.parse(params)`.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/books_controller",
      data: { list_authors: JSON.stringify(this.get('authors')) }
});
```

Comment: but what about the url ??

Comment: @Jadoo I do not know yr urls, just make sure passing right params and getting them right.